# Where has my precious intellisense data type information gone?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have been noticing that for the last couple versions of Visual Studio and only on some computers, my intellisense is not showing me datatypes in some places. I just managed to find a spot where it clearly knows the return type of a function after I type the parentheses (right side of image) but it doesn't show it before on the left side of the screenshot(s). This makes me a sad panda. Can anyone shed some light? I swear this seems to happen only on some machines. I just upgraded from 2012 to 2013 to see if it'd help. Hint: nope. Direct question time. 
Why is this happening? 
Can it be fixed? 
If so, how? 
Is it supposed to be this way?

Any information would be greatly appreciated! :)

Note: this doesn't seem to be specific to VB.net or C#
[image: two screenshots]

Comment: I have this issue too, sometimes Resharper also completely cracks up on me and says I have syntax errors. I've only found restarting VS and/or rebooting fixes it :-S I have noticed though that the longer my computer runs the more this occurs so it could be some weird cache corruption problem?

Comment: I have experienced this problem too. The only fix that I have found to work is to backup and reset my settings in Visual Studio.

Comment: Very interesting. I'm guessing a reboot might not help as my machine gets restarted fairly often. It's worth a shot though. I hadn't even thought of resetting the settings, that's a good idea! Not fun, but a good idea. I'll try to post back my findings.

Comment: maybe you should issue a bug entry to ms :-)